# Proof your answer(asumption)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$A$ is a bounded subset of $(0, \infty)$. $B$ is a subset of  $\mathbb{R}$ defined by $B=\{{\sqrt{a_1}-a_2} \text{ such that }a_1,a_2 \in A\}$. Compute $\sup(B)$ in terms of $\sup(A)$ and $\inf(A)$.

Comment: Do you mean $\sqrt{a_1-a_2}$ or $\sqrt{a_1}-a_2$?

Comment: Yes Erik i mean the later one the second one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: $\sup B=\sup\sqrt{A}-\inf A$. Intuitively, this is because $\sqrt{a}$ is an increasing function while $-a$ is a decreasing function. Can you prove the claim formally?

---

Here's the full answer, if you are still having trouble. It is more verbose than is ideal, but hopefully it leaves no stone left unturned.

Since $A$ is bounded and nonempty, we can find sequences $(\overline{a}_{n})_{n}$
and $(\underline{a}_{n})_{n}$such that $\overline{a}_{n}\rightarrow\sup A$
and $\underline{a}_{n}\rightarrow\inf A$. This allows us to construct
the sequence $(b_{n})_{n}$ given by $b_{n}=\sqrt{\overline{a}}_{n}-\underline{a}_{n}$.
Since limits and continuous functions commute,
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_{n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{\overline{a}_{n}}-\underline{a}_{n}=\sqrt{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\overline{a}_{n}}-\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\underline{a}_{n}=\sqrt{\sup A}-\inf A.
$$
It follows that $\sup B\geq\sqrt{\sup A}-\inf A$.

Now, to arrive at a contradiction, suppose $\sup B>\sqrt{\sup A}-\inf A$.
It follows that there exists some $b$ in $B$ and corresponding such
that $b>\sqrt{\sup A}-\inf A$. By the definition of $B$, this implies
the existence of $a_{1}$ and $a_{2}$ in $A$ such that $\sqrt{a_{1}}-a_{2}>\sqrt{\sup A}-\inf A$.

---

Once you get used to this argument, you can skip the details and simply
write 
$$
\sup B=\sup_{a_{1},a_{2}\in A}\sqrt{a_{1}}-a_{2}=\sup_{a_{1}\in A}\sqrt{a_{1}}+\sup_{a_{2}\in A}(-a_{2})=\sup_{a_{1}\in A}\sqrt{a_{1}}-\inf_{a_{2}\in A}a_{2}=\sup A-\inf A
$$

Comment: How did you know that supB=supA√−infA ?

Comment: I thank you so much. I really need a good book on real analysis or lets say, i used friendly intro from kumala but these things are not mentioned in there. Can you guys recommend a really good book on these things?

Comment: I think Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis is the standard undergraduate textbook. I know some people like Kolmogorov's Introductory Real Analysis too, but I am not familiar with it (though I own a dusty copy).